# NSData:writeToFile returning error "File doesn't exist"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm currently using the following code to write a NSData in a subfolder of the documents folder.

```
NSData* dataToSave=...;
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString* documentsDir=[
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) 
    objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* desiredFolder=[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MySubfolder"];
BOOL isDir;

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:desiredFolder isDirectory:&isDir]&&!isDir)
{
    NSError* error;
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:desiredFolder 
         withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}     
NSString* desiredFile=[desiredFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mfile.jpeg"];
if (![dataToSave writeToFile:desiredFile options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Error %@",error.localizedDescription);
    return NO;
}
```

It was working until I tested this config in "release mode" . There the NSData:writeToFile started to return `NO`, with the error: `The file 'myfile.jpeg´ doesn't exist`.

Where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: you mean `"/mfile.jpeg"` not  myfile.jpeg ?

Comment: also when you appendString string you should use `@"/"` but you are using `stringByAppendingPathComponent` pass fileName, not a slash

Comment: It was an transcript error, I'm using the version without '/', updated the question too

Comment: you declare and assign `desiredFile` but then use probably undeclared `itemImagePath`?

Comment: the condition `if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:desiredFolder isDirectory:&dirExist]&&!dirExist)` might be problematic. to me your code seems a bit to over careful. just keep it simple by using `[fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:desiredFolder withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];` and then `[dataToSave writeToFile:itemImagePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @mbi I found the answer.

The problem is when validating the existence of the parent folder:

```
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:desiredFolder isDirectory:&isDir]&&!isDir)
```

This is incorrect. Since the isDirectory param is unsafe `isDir` can be true even if the result of the method is `NO`. So the correct way to evaluate is just:

```
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:desiredFolder isDirectory:nil])
```

Or if you want to handle the case where the file exists but is not a directory:

```
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:desiredFolder isDirectory:&isDir]){
...
}else if(!isDir) {
...
}
```

Comment: I think this is correct, however I disagree that `isDir` can be `YES` when the method returns `NO`.  That makes no sense assuming you initialize `isDir` to `NO`.  A non-existent file cannot also be a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.

```
if (![dataToSave writeToFile:desiredFile atomically:YES])
{
    NSLog(@"Error writing to file : %@",desiredFile);
    return NO;
}
```